# How to find the largest palindromic subsequence in an array?

Tags: arrays

I've seen solutions on how to do this for strings such as on Geeksforgeeks (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-longest-palindromic-subsequence/) but when I tried doing this for an array it gave me really weird errors. For example, if I passed in the array [1,4,5,4,2,1], the answer it'd give me was 4541, and if used the array [5,3,6,4,7,3,8] it'd give me 73. It seems that for some reason it seems to consistently omit the first number that would make it a true palindrome and I don't know why.

This is my current code in python modified from geeksforgeeks to work with number arrays:

def lcs_(X, Y) :

```
m = len(X) 
n = len(Y)  

L = [[0] * (n + 1)] * (m + 1) 

# Following steps build L[m+1][n+1]  
# in bottom up fashion. Note that  
# L[i][j] contains length of LCS of  
# X[0..i-1] and Y[0..j-1] 
for i in range(n + 1) : 

    for j in range(n + 1) : 

        if (i == 0 or j == 0) : 
            L[i][j] = 0;  
        elif (X[i - 1] == Y[j - 1]) : 
            L[i][j] = L[i - 1][j - 1] + 1;  
        else : 
            L[i][j] = max(L[i - 1][j], 
                          L[i][j - 1]);  

# Following code is used to print LCS  
index = L[m][n];  

# Create a string length index+1 and  
# fill it with \0  
lcs = [0] * (index + 1) 

# Start from the right-most-bottom-most  
# corner and one by one store characters  
# in lcs[] 
i, j= m, n  

while (i > 0 and j > 0) : 

    # If current character in X[] and Y  
    # are same, then current character  
    # is part of LCS 
    if (X[i - 1] == Y[j - 1]) : 

        # Put current character in result  
        lcs[index - 1] = X[i - 1] 
        i -= 1
        j -= 1

        # reduce values of i, j and index  
        index -= 1

    # If not same, then find the larger of  
    # two and go in the direction of larger  
    # value  
    elif(L[i - 1][j] > L[i][j - 1]) : 
        i -= 1

    else : 
        j -= 1

ans = "" 

for x in range(len(lcs)) : 
    if (lcs[x]!=0):
            ans += str(lcs[x])

return ans
```

def longestPalSubseq(string) :

```
# Find reverse of str  
rev = string[: : -1] 

# Return LCS of str and its reverse  
return lcs_(string, rev)
```

if **name** == "**main**" :

```
string = [5,3,6,4,7,3,8]
print(longestPalSubseq(string))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I just don't know what's up here.